# Firefox: access the <img> tag generated after dropping a file from the Desktop to a HTML contenteditable element

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

Using Firefox, when I drop an image file from my Desktop into a HTML `contenteditable="true"` element, a `<img>` is created.

How can I get that `<img>` that is created after dropping the file from my desktop to a contenteditable element, for example, to set a value to the `alt` attribute or change its size ??

My try: I have thought maybe there is a way to retrived the last (cronologically) element inserted in the contentediable element.

```js
$("#editor").on("dragover", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(this).addClass('dragging');
});

$("#editor").on("dragleave", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(this).removeClass('dragging');
});

$("#editor").on("drop", function (event) {
  //how to access here the <img> created after dropping 
  //the file from the desktop
}
```

```css
p {
  height: 700px;
  width: 700px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="editor" contenteditable="true"></p>
```